# Random Loss of Internet connection over wifi in ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, internet

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS as dual-boot on my laptop and the Internet used to stop working randomly (say 10~15 minutes) though the wifi indicator shows connected.

Every time this happens I had to disconnect wifi in the network manager and then connect again for it to work again.

BTW wifi works well in windows 10.

[Details of my network card](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25039316/)

Laptop : Lenovo Ideapad 510 (80SV00FFIH).

EDIT 1: I have updated ubuntu 16.04LTS to Ubuntu 17.10(daily build) and the system is very stable except for the wifi problem.

This time Wifi is lost for about every 45 min or so.

[details of network card again after updating](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25059231/)

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your linux-headers to latest stable build **manually**. For example your linux-headers is version 4.10 upgrade it to version 4.12 manually, download them at [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12/) in this case i'm using 64bit ubuntu then i'm download this builds :

1. linux-headers-4.12.0-041200_4.12.0-041200.201707022031_all.deb
2. linux-headers-4.12.0-041200-generic_4.12.0-041200.201707022031_amd64.deb
3. linux-image-4.12.0-041200-generic_4.12.0-041200.201707022031_amd64.deb

install all of it `sudo dpkg -i <package name>` and remove the old one (version 4.10) the easiest way is by using synaptic package manager, you can google how to do it. Restart and don't forget to do your routine after that restart "`sudo apt udpate && sudo apt upgrade`". I'm newbie in linux but i hope this trick is work, cause is work for me. Cheers